# Trying to create a tool in Python that stores error codes and can display a total

Tags: python

```
#Error Code Collection

#Codes

ec80803 = 0

#Start

prompt = input("Code:")

if prompt == "80803":
  ec80803 += 1
print (ec80803)
```

So thats what I have so far, my question is how would I make it so it would go back to asking for the Code and then keep adding +1 each time its entered? as for now I enter 80803 it displays a 1, and thats it. Sorry if its a stupidly nooby question I'm really just starting to get into Python and wanted to have a go at making something. Thanks :)

Comment: You want a `while` loop https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop

Comment: You should try the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a loop of some sort - all programs quit when they reach the end. So something like this would work:

```
#Error Code Collection

#Codes

ec80803 = 0

#Start

try:
    while True:
        prompt = input("Code:")

        if prompt == "80803":
          ec80803 += 1
        print (ec80803)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Exiting")
```

This will continue asking for input until you exit the program (press ctrl+c). Without the `try`/`except` block you'd get an ugly stack trace when exiting.

Answer (score 0):

pop it in a while loop.

```
while(1):
    prompt = input("Code:")

    if prompt == "80803":
        ec80803 += 1
        print (ec80803)
```

Comment: Could you explain a little more? Code-only answers are discouraged here. Thanks.